# read() System call and Null-terminated string

Tags: c, system-calls

If I have the following array :

```
char message_buffer [100] ="Hello World ";
```

If I then use an ordinary pipe to send this buffer from the parent process to a child and then at the child , I have used the following code :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char message_buffer[100] = "Hello World ";
    char read_buffer[100];
    int return_value;
    int fd[2];
    return_value = pipe(fd);
    if (return_value < 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating the pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc  < 0)
    {
        printf("Error forking a child");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rc > 0)
    {
        printf("I am the parent , I will write the message now into the pipe. \n");
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], message_buffer, 100);
        close(fd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("I am the child , I will read the message from the pipe. \n");
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], read_buffer, 100);
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("Message recieved: %s", read_buffer);
    }
```

In this situation, the print statement will work without printing any garbage value. However, assume we have a file copying program that copies the content of a file to another file, where the source file will have the content "hello world" and then we read this message into a buffer and send it through a pipe to a child:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char childbuff[100];
    int fd[2], des, bytes, target;

    pipe(fd);

    if (fork())
    {
        /* parent process closes the downstream */
        close(fd[0]);

        /* reads the file */
        des = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
        bytes = read(des, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        /* puts data in pipe */
        write(fd[1], buffer, bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Child process closes the upstream */
        close(fd[1]);

        /* reads from the pipe */
        read(fd[0], childbuff, sizeof(childbuff));
        close(fd[0]);

        /* output the received string */
        printf("\nReceived string is -- %s", childbuff);
        target = open("copy.txt", O_CREAT, 00777);
        write(target, childbuff, (strlen(childbuff) - 1));
    }
}
```

In this case, I get a garbage value along the message received when I run the print statement. I know that the read() doesn't Null terminate the buffer. But my question is why the print statement has worked fine in the first case (in which we have only transferred an array), while it didn't work fine in the second case (in which we have transferred a content of a file)?

Comment: Don't just describe parts of the code in words. Provide a complete [mre] that illustrates the issue. For example, it matters how the write side is coded and you have not shown that. But it seems fairly straight forward - if the write side sends a terminating NUL then the read side will get it otherwise it will not. Text files never contain the NUL character. So the write side needs to add that itself before sending it if it wants to send a C string.

Comment: @kaylum Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: @kaylum Does in the first case  the compiler will add automatically the NULL terminating character as the size of the array is big enough to include it ? That's why it has worked in the first case?

Comment: No you added it. `char message_buffer [100] ="Hello World ";` will initialise `message_buffer` with the string - which includes the terminating NUL.

Comment: @kaylum So this means that the NULL character will be written and sent by the parent and then will be read by the read() in the child and that's why it will work in the first case. Is that right? Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Yes that's right. (You are also sending all the zeroes after the first NUL character which is a bit wasteful BTW).

Comment: You write 100 bytes to the pipe in the first example, but the last 88 of them are null bytes.  In the second example, you only write as many bytes as were read, and there is no null byte at the end, so your code doesn't have a string to print, and you get garbage instead.  You could use `char childbuff[100] = "";` in the second example so that the read overwrites a bunch of nulls, but unless there were actually 100 bytes sent of the pipe, you'd still have a null-terminated string.  Pay attention to how much data was written and read.  Don't try printing data that was not read.